The gap distribution of the random variables.
Randomly sampling $n$ numbers from the Normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, whose PDF and CDF are $f(a)$ and $F(a)$, respectively.. We can get a list of number $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$. Sort the numbers and then we can get the gaps between two consecutive numbers:
$\{a_{(2)}-a_{(1)},\dots ,a_{(n)}-a_{(n-1)}\}$
Let $G_i$ be the gap at the left of number $a_{(i)}$, i.e. $a_{(i)}-a_{(i-1)}$. What is the distribution of $G_i$?

This would be much easier drawing from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ where the gaps would have density $n(1-x)^{n-1}$

Thanks for the reply. How to obtain this result? Is there any reference? :)

Drawing from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is easy enough to calculate as all the gaps are identically distributed, as are $x_{(1)}-0$ and $1-x_{(n)}$: the CDF is $1-(1-x)^n$ and you can then differentiate.  That does not work for a normal distribution, as they are not identically distributed while $x_{(1)}-(-\infty)$ and $\infty-x_{(n)}$ are of course infinite. There is some symmetry from the symmetry of the normal distribution:  $x_{(k)}-x_{(k-1)}$ and $x_{(n-k+2)}-x_{(n-k+1)}$ have the same distribution.

Can I interpret the CDF $1−(1−x)^n$ by the negation of all numbers are greater than x?  If so, why does this require the assumption that the gaps between the ordered observations are identically distributed? Furthermore, for the normal distribution, can we derive a similar result $1-(1-F(x))^n$?

Sampling from a uniform distribution, it uses the "identically distributed" to say we only need to look at $x_{(1)}-0$ and the CDF is then indeed the negation of all the $x_i > x$.  It does not work for a normal distribution because (a) gaps are not uniformly distributed (gaps near the middle tend to be smaller) and (b) instead of $x_{(1)}-0$ you would have $x_{(1)}-(-\infty)$.  For any continuous distribution including a normal distribution you can say $F(x_{(k)})-F(x_{(k-1)})$ has CDF  $1-(1-x)^n$ and density $n(1-x)^{n-1}$; this does not help with the distribution of $x_{(k)}-x_{(k-1)}$

Let $F(x)$ be the CDF of your continuous random variable $X_j$ and $f(x)$ its density; you have $n$ of them and $i\in\{2,3,\dots,n\}$. For given two real numbers $a<b$, the probability that $k:=i-1$ of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ lie below $x$ and $n-k$ of them lie above $y$ is
$$
Q:=\binom{n}{k} F(x)^k\cdot\left(1-F(y)\right)^{n-k}
$$
since the probability that $\mathbb{P}(X_1\le x,\dots X_k\le x)=F(x)^k$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_{k+1}\ge x,\dots X_n\ge x)=(1-F(x))^{n-k}$  by independence, and there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ variables amongst $n$.
Therefore, the joint density of the largest $k^{th}$ and $k+1^{st}$ largest variable is
\begin{align}
\tilde f(x,y):=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}Q
&=\binom{n}{k} k F(x)^{k-1} f(x)\cdot(n-k)\left(1-F(y)\right)^{n-k-1}f(y)
\\ &=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}  F(x)^{k-1} f(x)\cdot\left(1-F(y)\right)^{n-k-1}f(y)
\end{align}
Now to get the distribution of $G_{i-1}=\tilde G_{k}$, you not that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tilde G_k\le b)=\iint_{0\le y-x\le b} \tilde f(x,y) dxdy
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left( \int_{x}^{x+b}\tilde f(x,y) dy \right)dx
$$
and its density
\begin{align}
f_{\tilde G_k}(b)=\frac{d}{db}\mathbb{P}(\tilde G_k\le b)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\tilde f(x,x+b) dx
\\&=n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)^{k-1} f(x)\cdot\left(1-F(x+b)\right)^{n-k-1}f(x+b)dx
\end{align}

Hi, thanks for the answer. But I am confused of using partial derivative of the $Q$ derives the density of $k^{th}$ and $k+1^{th}$ variables.

If you gave two (possibly dependent) random variables, their joint cdf is defined as $$F_{X,Y}(ab)=\mathbb{P}(X\le a, Y\le b)$$ and then the joint density is $$f_{X,Y}(a,b)=\frac{\partial^2 F_{X,Y}(a,b)}{\partial a\partial b}.$$ You can derive it from there, by observing that $$\mathbb{P}(X\le a, Y\le  b)=\mathbb{P}(X\le a)-\mathbb{P}(X\le a, Y>b).$$

I understand your explanation. However, my question actually lies in the reasoning behind $Q$ being the joint cumulative distribution function (cdf) that you mentioned. Your notations includes some typos and are a little confused to me, could you detail them further? This additional clarification would greatly aid my comprehension of the underlying concept.

Thank you for the updated explanation and I understand the idea. However, I have one more question. If the joint density is obtained, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde{f}(x,x+b) dx$ would directly yield $\mathbb{P}(G_{k}=b)$ as the result. Why is it necessary to include the discussion of $\mathbb{P}(G_{k} \leq b)$ in this context? Regardless, I will vote for your answer.

It seems you mix up CDF and the density. The probabilty that $G=b$ is zero for all $b$ as it is a continuous random variable.
